# Four lane SFF-8088 to SFF-8470 cable, 6G/12G

Tags: hardware, storage, hp, sas

I need a couple of SFF-8088 to SFF-8470 cables and the HP manual says the HP 408771-001 is the right one for me. My hardware dealer has them in stock for about 100$. I browsed a bit and found the HP AE466A for about a third of the price, but since it's explictly labelled as four-lane cable, could it be that it cannot handle 6G or 12G connections? At 2m it's even twice as long as the originally suggested cable so it seems a bit fishy.

Any pointers to datasheets my google search did not lead me to are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What are you connecting to what?

Comment: An HP MSA2000 to some HBA, I think it's the OEM version of the LSI 9207-8e

Answer (score 2):

Connections for a SAS-based HP P2000 or MSA2000 SAN to the host should be standard SAS SFF-8088 male connectors on both ends.

[image]

If your HBA has a SAS SFF-8470 port (CX-4 Infiniband type), it's probably not the best HBA for this purpose. However you can just use the proper cable. Cost doesn't matter. SAS is a standard, so get whatever meets your needs.

[image]

Comment: Hmm... My MSA2000 looks like this http://imgur.com/xR2wcPs so I've got 8470 at the shelf and 8088 at the HBA side of things.

Comment: That's an MSA2000 drive enclosure (AJ750A). It's not a SAN, but just an expansion shelf. It's also very old. Can you please provide some specific details on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Erm.. specific details? Just connect it to a HBA. Connect a cable between the shelf and the HBA. That's it. The question is, is a four lane cable always 'good enough' for 3G/6G/12G or are there specific 6G/12G cables.

Comment: Okay, that's not enough info. What are you seeking from this setup? Nothing in this setup is 12Gbps SAS. The unit you're connecting to is an expansion shelf meant to be connected to an HP SAN, not as a JBOD to an HBA. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Well, yes, it's 6G afaik. The original question was, does one have to buy specific 6G and/or 12G cable or will any four lane cable give me the full 4x 3/6/12G bandwidth.
You are correct, that this shelf is probably not intended to be used as a JBOD. Didn't really cross my mind since the orignal question was about the cables. Sorry I didn't make myself more clear. But since you brought it up: Could you actually connect the shelf in the imgur link to let's say an 9207-8e with an 8088 to 8470 cable? Would the OS see some JBOD devices?

Comment: The cables won't matter. This shelf is a 3Gbps SAS shelf/controllers and backplane, so speeds will downshift to that when connected to a 6Gbps HBA. If you put SATA disks in the shelf, you may end up with 1.5Gbps link speeds on the disks. No idea if this enclosure will work as a JBOD. You haven't given details on your end goal.

Comment: Oh, you are correct once again. The MSA2000 is a 3Gbit/s model. The end goal is to connect some drives as JBOD to some server. That's it.
But since they are 3Gbit/s I think I'll toss them then. Thanks anyway. The more interesting question is, would the cable matter. Does any four lane cable work for 6 or 12Gbit/s. I've got a couble of 6Gbit/s MD3060e and 12GBit/s MD1400 here. They do come with the cables, but it'll be nice to know that I could just use any cable there.

Comment: Any cable with the right connectors will work.